# Hilbert space compression of lamplighter over lamplighter groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

$C_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ is the lamplighter group but I'm currently looking at the lamplighter group with this group as a base space.

**Question:** Consider the group $C_2 \wr (C_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$, what is its compression exponent?

[EDIT: I just noticed this is mentioned as an open question by Naor & Peres in *$L^p$ Compression, traveling salesmen and stable walks*. I also changed the upcoming paragraphs which gave a false estimate]

Note that the Cayley graph of the group $F \wr (F \wr \mathbb{Z})$ are not Liouville (the fact it has speed exponent 1 is also given by Naor & Peres in *Embeddings of Discrete Groups and the Speed of Random
Walks* at (8)). So its compression exponent is at most $\tfrac{1}{2}$ (and I'm inclined to think it has exactly this exponent).